# Password protecting and only allowing one IP address to access a directory?

Tags: apache, security, .htaccess

I have a directory on my website that I need to make sure no one but myself can get into. From the reading I've done, it looks like there are two ways to protect a directory:

1. Password protect the directory using the .htaccess file
2. Deny access to all IP addresses but my own from accessing the directory, also using the .htaccess file

I need to protect the files in the directory as securely as possible, so I figured I'd use both of those methods for double protection.

Question 1: Am I missing anything? (i.e. is there another layer of protection I can add?)

Question 2: What would I need to put in a .htaccess file to get the above to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your .htaccess file would contain:

```
AuthUserFile /usr/local/nate/safe_place/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Protected Files"
AuthType Basic

require user nate
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

The `.htaccess` file goes in the directory you're trying to protect.

You also need a .htpasswd file (shown above as `/usr/local/nate/safe_place/.htpasswd`) which contains the text username:password_hash.  So if we use "nate" as an example and "secret" as the password (please don't use that) you get:

```
nate:XmN6pwFyy3Il2
```

You can use this tool to generate your own password file:  http://www.tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

Just make sure that no one can read your `.htpasswd` file.  Also note that basic authentication does no encryption by itself.  If you're on an open network, anyone can see your password and all the secret data going over the network.  Make sure you visit your site via https if it's really that secret.

You can read more about `.htaccess` files here:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

Comment: I tried making a .htaccess file in the directory I need to protect and added the following: `AuthUserFile /home/username/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Protected Files"
AuthType Basic`, but when I load a page from the directory, no login prompt happens. The pages still load.

Comment: Try these troubleshooting steps:  `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html#troubleshoot`

Comment: I tried putting garbage in the .htaccess file like that page said, and no error was displayed.

Comment: Well, the guide said "A good test for this is to put garbage in your .htaccess file and reload. If a server error is not generated, then you almost certainly have AllowOverride None in effect."  So now read `https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride`, that means that you have to change your AllowOverride directive.  I don't know what yours is set to now, but you need at least `AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit` if you don't want to put `AllowOverride All` into your `httpd.conf`.  Note that you will have to restart Apache after changing its config file (`apachectl graceful`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're running Apache and have an `AllowOverride` directive permitting `.htaccess` files to use `<Limit>`, the following should be a good starting place for you:

```
<Limit GET>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from IP_ADDRESS_HERE
</Limit>
```

More documentation on `<Limit>`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limit
and for access control: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

Comment: The Limit directive isn't a good choice. What about HEAD, PUT, DELETE, ...? You don't actually need any enclosing directive around this if it's in a .htaccess file, and if it isn't it should be in a Location directive.